# Moving value from end of int array to the beginning in Java

Tags: java, arrays, int

I have an array of type int:

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
array[2] = 3
array[3] = 4
array[4] = 5
```

I want to take the value at the end, and bring it the beginning and shunt the rest of the elements to the right, so my output will look like: 5, 1, 2, 3, 4

I've considered using an ArrayList, but the assignment seems to want me to just use a primitive array.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far ? That's quite simple.

Comment: It would be easier with LinkedList

Comment: do temp = array [4], then move all the elements of the array up by one, like array [1] = array [0] then finally make array [0] = temp. Thats the algorithm

Comment: I tried using an ArrayList, but i don't think that's what they are looking for. It's homework for my java class yes. Well, a small part of a project on inversion.

Comment: @jgr208 Did what you suggested with a for loop. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code, try this

```
public class arrayformat {

    public static void main(String[] s)
    {
                int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};


                int temp = array[4];

                for(int i=array.length-1;i>0;i--)
                {
                    array[i]=array[i-1];
                }

                array[0]= temp;

                for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(array[i]);
                }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont need an ArrayList or a LinkedList to achieve that.
I'm not going to give you a full solution but try to think about what you know about arrays and what you want to achieve (which value should be placed where (try to work with the array's index)).
If you dont have to do an inplace reversion it can be very helpful to create a second array to work with.
Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html for a introduction to java arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can try next:

```
    int arr[] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    int val = arr[arr.length-1];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr, 1, arr.length-1);
    arr[0] = val;
```